# Will other truths be checked if the first is successful in `OR if-checks`

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, optimization

I can't test this well but I was wondering if someone might know this. Having this simple check

```
if ([dict objectForKey:@"key"] != nil || [a isEqualToString:b] || someIntValue> 12) { ... }
```

Obviously (no matter the small margin) the first check will probably be *heavier* than the second, and the third even *lighter*.

So my question is; will the binary in my app still check the other 2 statements if the first was already `true`? Because if so I was thinking of doing a small round checks in my code-base to tweak checks like those above to move the simple `int` comparison earlier in that if-statement.

p.s.

I know you can't check unexisting objects in Objective-C like you can in PHP and I also only mean existing objects in this example, not to do something *hacky* that object(s) in the second statement won't exist:

```
$a = 0; $b = '';

if ($a == 0 || $i_dont_exist > 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Would that imply that even if the `object` is nil, the parser will accept a second check after it to access the `object` (`myString.length`) because it passed the nil-check? That sounds creepily unsafe.

Comment: "*I can't test this well*" – Sure you can. Just setup two test methods that both return a true boolean, and NSLog something when they're called. Then put these in an if statement with an OR operator, and you'll see that only the first is evaluated.

Comment: @Allendar If the first condition, `[dict objectForKey:@"key"] != nil`, is true then the rest of the conditions will be skipped and the body of the `if` statement will be executed.

Comment: That makes sense thanks. And yes @originaluser2 you're right I could've tested it like that. I just did it and saw it worked. I'm gonna refactor my code now to move some lighter checks to the front of my `if`-statements to get some overall speed boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Objective-C is a strict superset of C, since C supports short-circuit evaluation so does Objective-C.

So if the first condition in an "or" statement is true the rest of the conditions should not be evaluated.